# the firebase getToken() function

Tags: cordova, firebase, firebase-authentication

Do you need to register the user first in order to use the getIdToken() Javascript function?
Can someone give an example of how to use this function and where.
I have my `index.html` and in it I have included:

```
 https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.6.2/firebase.js`.
```

I have this code:-

```
 firebase.auth().currentUser.getToken(true).then(function(idToken) { 
 alert(idToken);
 }).catch(function (error) {
 });
```

but this gives me

> currentUser is null error.

Comment: did you authenticate the user first?

Comment: I confused the registration token with authentication token. I found the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client)

Comment: yup thats true, that is why I asked you about authentication

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to get user credentials but still want to distinguish them,
you can take a look at [Anonymous Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth).

```
firebase.auth().signInAnonymously();
```

is enough to log an user in.